# RSA turning string to BigInteger

Tags: java, rsa, biginteger

I am playing around with an RSA Algorithm program and trying to make it accept a string as the message instead of a number. I thought I had the conversion right but I get an error when I run, can anyone see why?

```
    import java.math.BigInteger;
    import java.security.SecureRandom;


    public class rsa {

       //declaring random for use in pub and private gen 
       private final static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

       //declarring bigInts
       private BigInteger privateKey;
       private BigInteger publicKey;
       private BigInteger modulus;

       // generate an N-bit (roughly) public and private key
       rsa(int N) {
          BigInteger p = BigInteger.probablePrime(N/2, random);
          BigInteger q = BigInteger.probablePrime(N/2, random);
          BigInteger phi = p.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
          phi = phi.multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1)));

          modulus    = p.multiply(q);                                  
          publicKey  = new BigInteger("65537");     // common value in practice = 2^16 + 1
          privateKey = publicKey.modInverse(phi);
       }


       //encrypting function
       BigInteger encrypt(BigInteger message) {
          return message.modPow(publicKey, modulus);
       }

       //decrypting function
       BigInteger decrypt(BigInteger encrypted) {
          return encrypted.modPow(privateKey, modulus);
       }

       //printing values
       public String toString() {
          String s = "";
          s += "public = " + publicKey  + "\n";
          s += "private = " + privateKey + "\n";
          s += "modulus = " + modulus;
          return s;
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {

          //declaring n (numbrer of bytes)
          int N = 128;

          //new object key RSA
          rsa key = new rsa(N);

          //printing the key
          System.out.println("key = " + key);

          // create message by converting string to integer
           String s = "test";
           byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
           BigInteger message = new BigInteger(s);

          //encryting message
          BigInteger encrypt = key.encrypt(message);

          //decrypting encryption
          BigInteger decrypt = key.decrypt(encrypt);

          //printing values
          System.out.println("message   = " + message);
          System.out.println("encrpyted = " + encrypt);
          System.out.println("decrypted = " + decrypt);
       }
    }
```

And this is the error I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "test"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:461)
at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:597)
at rsa.main(rsa.java:64)
```

Comment: "test" is not a number.

Comment: Well, "test" sure isn't a BigInteger value representation.

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "test"` Tells you literally everything you need to know.

Comment: An IDE generally makes it clear when a variable is unused which `bytes` in this case and the whole problem wouldn't have been made a SO issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at that part of your code

```
String s = "test";
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
BigInteger message = new BigInteger(s);
```

Now let's have a look at the documentation of the [constructor of BigInteger which accept a String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String)).

> Translates the decimal String representation of a BigInteger into a
>   BigInteger. The String representation consists of an optional minus
>   sign followed by a sequence of one or more decimal digits. The
>   character-to-digit mapping is provided by Character.digit. The String
>   may not contain any extraneous characters (whitespace, for example).

`"test"` is certainly not a String representation of a BigInteger.

It seems like you wanted to call the [constructor passing in a byte array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(byte[])).

> Translates a byte array containing the two's-complement binary
>   representation of a BigInteger into a BigInteger. The input array is
>   assumed to be in big-endian byte-order: the most significant byte is
>   in the zeroth element.

This code

```
String s = "test";
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
BigInteger message = new BigInteger(bytes);
System.out.println(message);
```

would print 1952805748

Comment: That helped quite a lot very informative thank you! I see now my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Try `BigInteger message = new BigInteger(bytes);` instead of `BigInteger message = new BigInteger(s);`